# send() function in selenium python is not working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import os, time, keyword, re, getpass, urllib, requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
Decision_from = input("Enter the Date From (DD-MM-YYYY):- ")
download_dir = "d:/dirName"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("plugin.state.flash", 0)
profile.set_preference("plugin.state.java", 0)
profile.set_preference("media.autoplay.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
# whether or not to show the Downloads window when a download begins.
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                       "application/octet-stream" +
                       ",application/zip" +
                       ",application/x-rar-compressed" +
                       ",application/x-gzip" +
                       ",application/msword")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, executable_path=r'd:/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://dsscic.nic.in/cause-list-report-web/view-decision/1")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('form-control').send_keys(Decision_from)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='submit']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page_length']/option[text()='5000']").click()
rows = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapperContent']/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/table/tbody[2]/tr"))
columns = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='wrapperContent']/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/table/tbody[2]/tr/td"))
suni="//*[@id='wrapperContent']/div/div/div/section/div/div/div/table/tbody[2]/tr["
ashu="]/td[9"
pansing="]/form/button"
for t_row in range(1, (rows + 1)):
    if t_row == 1:
        print("Hello Jaaneman First Row Empty")
    else:
        Final_Path = suni + str(t_row) + ashu + pansing
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(Final_Path).click()
        handles = driver.window_handles
        size = len(handles)
        parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
        if handles[1] != parent_handle:#if handles[2] != parent_handle:
            driver.switch_to.window(handles[1])#driver.switch_to.window(handles[2])
            ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys("F", "A").key_up(Keys.ALT).send_keys(Keys.HOME)
            driver.close()
        driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)
```

All program run properly but "ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys("F", "A").key_up(Keys.ALT).send_keys(Keys.HOME)" not working. how to resolve it.

i'm newly for selenium python. Please guide to me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.perform()` at the end:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys("F", "A").key_up(Keys.ALT).send_keys(Keys.HOME).perform()
```

From the documentation:

> When you call methods for actions on the ActionChains object, the actions are stored in a queue in the ActionChains object. When you call perform(), the events are fired in the order they are queued up.

Comment: ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys("F").send_keys("A").key_up(Keys.ALT).send_keys(Keys.HOME).perform()

but not working

Comment: which type of problem Browser or other type.

Please solve me